# Check for an specific .js file being served in response

Tags: javascript, ruby, network-programming, monitoring

I need to detect whether an specific .js file was served in a http response  and additionally, check the domain it came from, like this:

[image: js from domain]

I need to automatically detect the lack of the js file and email the incidence

I tried Net::Http, rest-client, mechanize and a lot of gems, they just return the html header. It seems I need to monitor http traffic with tools like [PhantomJS and checking for the file](http://phantomjs.org/network-monitoring.html), but is there any rubyesque way of doing this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I ended with the phantomjs approach. A ruby script iterate over a database table and then calls this phantomjs script for each record representing an URL

This is the phantomjs script

```js
var page = require('webpage').create(),
    system = require('system'),
    address,
    isScript = false;
var fs = require('fs');



// main
analizePage(system.args[1]);

//open page.
//onResourceRequested event, compares domain of each one with 'my.domain.net'
//append to a log file: -1 for failed url, 1 for script presence, 0 for no script presence 
function analizePage(address){
  page.open(address, function (status) {
      if (status !== 'success') {
          console.log('FAIL to load the address ' + address);
          fileWriter(-1, address);
      }
   else
   {
  if (!isScript){
   fileWriter(0, address);
  }
  else
  {
   fileWriter(1, address);
  }
    console.log('Has script: ' + isScript);
   }
 phantom.exit(0);

 });

 page.onResourceRequested = function (req) {
   try {
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.setAttribute('href', req.url); //extract asset's domain from URL

    if (link.hostname == 'my.domain.net') {
       isScript = true;
      }
   } catch(e) {
    console.log("PAGE OPEN ERROR: " + e);
   }
 };

}


function fileWriter(type, line){
 try {
  fs.write("scriptlog.csv", type + ',' + line + ',' + Date.now() + ',' + system.args[2] + '\n', 'a');
  } catch(e) {
      console.log("FILE ERROR: " + e);
  }
}
```